# Cannot invoke + with an argument of type CGRect error in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, cgrect, cgrectmake

I want to initiate an instance of `UITableView` from `CGRectMake` function, but when I tried to initiate it using constants instead of directly assigning a new `Int`, such as:

```
UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(20, HEIGHT_OF_STATUS_AND_NAVIGATION_BAR + 120, tableWidth, tableHeight)
```

, then I got an error: `Int is not convertible to CGFloat`.

So I changed it to the following code:

```
UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(20, (HEIGHT_OF_STATUS_AND_NAVIGATION_BAR + 120) as CGFloat, tableWidth as CGFloat, tableHeight as CGFloat)) // `tableWidth` and `tableHeight` are both of type `Int`.
```

, then I got an error: `Cannot invoke + with an argument of type CGRect`.

Of course I can initiate it by just assigning `Int`, such as `CGRectMake(20 + 300 + 12, 44 + 120, 300, 480)`. But I want to use constant and variable.

So what does the error mean? And how can I fix it?

I use Xcode 6 beta 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way @Martin R does works well, but later I found that there are no reasons to bother to use `CGFloat()` - you can just use `CGRect()` instead of `CGRectMake()` in Swift, on which you can specify the argument as `Int` as well as `Double` or `CGFloat` to all the `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` properties as long as all the four properties are of the same type. Also, you cannot omit the name of each property which you can in the case of `CGRectMake()`, but this is easier, more flexible, and considered to be the default `CGRect` initializer in Swift.

Answer (score 3):

An `Int` cannot be converted to `CGFloat` with the `... as CGFloat` notation.

You have to construct `CGFloat`s from the `Int`s:

```
let frame = CGRectMake(20.0, CGFloat(HEIGHT_OF_STATUS_AND_NAVIGATION_BAR + 120), CGFloat(tableWidth), CGFloat(tableHeight))
```

Comment: Thanks. But why is `Int` not convertible to `CGFloat`?

Comment: @Gardecolo: `as` is the "type cast operator" used for downcasting, not for conversion between different types.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your constant a float by adding ".0" at the end of it, and ".0" at the end of any value you pass like "120.0".

Sizes should be CGFloat instead of Int.

That should work.

Comment: It doesn't. It says "." postfix is a reserved